# Whats wrong with this code loop in python pynput loop indent wrong

Tags: python, while-loop

7.0 and I am wanting to know what I've done wrong with this code. I want it to loop infinitely and say vcmine start but I've done I've tried using for while and tried spamming the code over and over I just want it to print this code into a game so that I don't have to be at my pc but I can only get it to work with it only saying it once please help I've something wrong and I don't know what

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller ()

while True:
for char in "vcmine start":
    keyboard.press(char)
    keyboard.release(char)
    time.sleep(0.03)
    break
while True:
    keyboard.press(key.enter)
    keyboard.press(key.enter)
    break
```

Comment: i think your code is not properly identated. Also probably you missplaced the `break`

Comment: remove the `break` if you want to let it run forever

Comment: sorry im new to this could you please show me fixed example im not good at this

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is :

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
keyboard = Controller ()

while True:
    for char in "vcmine start":
        keyboard.press(char)
        keyboard.release(char)
        time.sleep(0.03)
    keyboard.press(key.enter)
    time.sleep(0.03)
    keyboard.press(key.enter)
    time.sleep(0.03)
```